# How to use qualifiedDouble when creatingThickness()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to create a Thickness of 6cm, I am not able to set the size in cm, I am looking at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.thickness%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I do not know how to use qualifiedDouble

```
string qualifiedDouble = "6cm";
flowDoc.ColumnWidth = Convert.ToDouble(new Thickness(qualifiedDouble));
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [LengthConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.lengthconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
LengthConverter lc = new LengthConverter();
string qualifiedDouble = "6cm";

double converted = (double)lc.ConvertFrom(qualifiedDouble);
flowDoc.ColumnWidth = converted;
```

Comment: You're missing a cast: `(double)lc.ConvertFrom(qualifiedDouble)`

Answer (score 0):

The qualified doubles end up going through a factor conversion based on the unit you give it, but as part of LengthConverter

```
LengthConverter lc = new LengthConverter();
string qualifiedDouble = "6cm";
var convertFrom = lc.ConvertFrom(qualifiedDouble);
if (convertFrom != null)
{
     double converted = (double) convertFrom;
}
```

P.S.:Originally Posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1279304/1172862)